# Is it possible to use gunicorn for my Django app inside a WSL Ubuntu system?

Tags: django, gunicorn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on a Windows 10 machine using Ubuntu inside WSL. I did this because I cannot get gunicorn to work as I've researched it is not available in Windows. I can successfully run my app using my docker-compose file within my WSL Ubuntu perfectly fine. I then run the gunicorn myapp.wsgi command and the server spins up with the terminal giving me the following output:

```
[2021-09-16 19:11:53 +0000] [25] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-09-16 19:11:53 +0000] [25] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (25)
[2021-09-16 19:11:53 +0000] [25] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-09-16 19:11:53 +0000] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
```

However, I cannot connect to my site at localhost:8000. I also did a curl request against the localhost:8000 from inside my docker container and got a 302 error.

I've researched using gunicorn, mod_wsgi and uwsgi, all given as options in the Django documentation. However, I want to use gunicorn or uwsgi to have access to either nginx or Apache (plus the documentation on mod_wsgi has a dead link for the windows install file). Does anyone have suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Comment: I have the same issue. Found a solution‽

Comment: No, I did not get anywhere with this.